# Nested <li> not working on slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code. I applied a hide/show functionality on button click. It works great but only the first value of the sub-list shows. Didn't know what  broke. Can some one help me?

```
<div ><button id="showmenu" type="button">Show menu</button></div>
   <div class="sidebarmenu" style="display: none;">
    <ul id="sidebarmenu1">
      <li><a href="#" >Circle List</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="addCircle.jsp">Add</a></li>
          <li><a href="EditDiv.jsp">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="deletediv.jsp">Delete</a></li>
          <li><a href="adddivision.jsp">View All</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>       
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('#showmenu').text($('.sidebarmenu').is(':visible') ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
    $('.sidebarmenu').toggle("slide");
});
});
```

This is my  CSS

```
.sidebarmenu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font: bold 12px verdana;
width: 180px; /* Main Menu Item widths */
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }

 .sidebarmenu ul li {
position: relative;
 }

/* Top level menu links style */
.sidebarmenu ul li a {
display: block;
overflow: auto; /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px;
border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:link,.sidebarmenu ul li a:visited,.sidebarmenu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #d2d2d2 /*background of tabs (default state)*/
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:visited {
color: black;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:hover {
background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

/*Sub level menu items */
.sidebarmenu ul li ul {
position: absolute;
width: 89px; /*Sub Menu Items width */

top: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

.sidebarmenu a.subfolderstyle{
  background: url(../images/right.PNG) no-repeat 97% 50%;
}

/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .sidebarmenu ul li {
float: left;
height: 1%;
}

* html .sidebarmenu ul li a {
height: 1%;
}
```

This is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Nested Side Bar Menu (Mar 20th, 09)
//By Dynamic Drive: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/

var menuids = [ "sidebarmenu1" ] //Enter id(s) of each Side Bar Menu's main UL, separated by commas

function initsidebarmenu() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < menuids.length; i++) {
        var ultags = document.getElementById(menuids[i])
                .getElementsByTagName("ul")
        for ( var t = 0; t < ultags.length; t++) {
            ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className += " subfolderstyle"
            if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id == menuids[i]) //if this is a first level submenu
                ultags[t].style.left = ultags[t].parentNode.offsetWidth
                        + "px" //dynamically position first level submenus to be width of main menu item
            else
                //else if this is a sub level submenu (ul)
                ultags[t].style.left = ultags[t - 1]
                        .getElementsByTagName("a")[0].offsetWidth
                        + "px" //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover = function() {
                this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "block"
            }
            ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout = function() {
                this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none"
            }
        }
        for ( var t = ultags.length - 1; t > -1; t--) { //loop through all sub menus again, and use "display:none" to hide menus (to prevent possible page scrollbars
            ultags[t].style.visibility = "visible"
            ultags[t].style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", initsidebarmenu, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", initsidebarmenu)
</script>
```

Note: I posted only a part of HTML. There are more items in my list and the complete sub-list appears fine when there is no slide functionality applied.

Comment: Seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/8nbe4/

Comment: Its working fine in fiddle. But its not working on my local server. I have some CSS on the list.

Comment: Show your css then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list inside the first list item disappears because you've got `visibility: hidden;` on it. If you delete that part - it will be shown **above** the parent list item as you set the `top: 0;` property. I changed it to 100% - and that's what I got. Is this what you want? -http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/8nbe4/1/

**EDIT:**

Since you don't have any classes on your html, the script, provided in the fiddle, can and should be refactored. Consider changing your html and css to include some classes.
The working example of the code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/8nbe4/2/

Comment: I want the sub list to be displayed to the right when hovered on "Circle List"

Comment: Does jQuery and JS conflict by any chance? Can you have a look at my updated JS?

Comment: I don't really know if it conflicts or not, probably console errors will tell you better. But I DO know that this submenu can be opened by pure css without any unneeded scripts ;) http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/8nbe4/3/

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `visibility:hidden` and `top:0`

check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/RLGMj/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showmenu').click(function() {
   $('#showmenu').text($('.sidebarmenu').is(':visible') ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
   $('.sidebarmenu').toggle("slide");
 });
});
```